# How to get contents of System.Net.Mail.Attachment

Tags: c#, email-attachments

I have a System.Net.Mail.Attachment object with some .csv data in it. I need to save the contents of the attachment in a file. I tried this:

```
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("Accounts,JOB,Usage Count");


            sb.AppendLine("One,Two,Three");
            sb.AppendLine("One,Two,Three");
            sb.AppendLine("One,Two,Three");

        var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString()));
        //Add a new attachment to the E-mail message, using the correct MIME type
        var attachment = new Attachment(stream, new ContentType("text/csv"))
        {
            Name = "theAttachment.csv"
        };


            var sr = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Blah\Look.csv");
            sr.WriteLine(attachment.ContentStream.ToString());
            sr.Close();
```

But the file has only the following: "System.IO.MemoryStream".
Could you please tell me how I can get the real data there?

Thanks.

Comment: Use file writer to write that stream to a file?

Comment: You can't call `ToString` on a random stream, that'll usually just print the type name. You need to use `CopyTo` to copy the stream to another stream.

Comment: If it's not too big, you can probably just call `ContentStream.ReadToEnd()`

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia That won't work because `ContentStream` is just a `System.IO.Stream`, not a `TextReader`. Even with a cast, it may fail.

Comment: Without ToString() I got the same result.

Comment: So is there any way to get that content from the Attachment?

Comment: ContentStream.ReadToEnd() worked, thanks!

Comment: @Kevin DiTraglia, if you make your idea an Answer, I will mark it as solution. Thanks.

Comment: It was like this: var sr = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Blah\Look.csv");
    var srr = new StreamReader(attachment.ContentStream);
                sr.WriteLine(srr.ReadToEnd());
                sr.Close();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your stream isn't too big you can just write it all to the file like so:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Blah\Look.csv"); 
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(attachment.ContentStream); 
writer.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd()); 
writer.Close();
```

If it is bigger you probably want to chunk the reads up into a loop as to not demolish your RAM (and risk out of memory exceptions).

Answer (score 6):

You can't call `ToString` on an arbitrary stream. Instead you should use `CopyTo`:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\Look.csv", FileMode.Create))
{
    attachment.ContentStream.CopyTo(fs);
}
```

Use this to replace the last three lines of your example. By default, `ToString` just returns that name of the type unless the class overrides ToString. ContentStream is just the abstract Stream (at runtime it is a `MemoryStream`), so there is just the default implementation.

`CopyTo` is new in .NET Framework 4. If you aren't using the .NET Framework 4, you can mimic it with an extension method:

```
public static void CopyTo(this Stream fromStream, Stream toStream)
{
    if (fromStream == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("fromStream");
    if (toStream == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("toStream");

    var bytes = new byte[8092];
    int dataRead;
    while ((dataRead = fromStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) > 0)
        toStream.Write(bytes, 0, dataRead);
}
```

Credit to Gunnar Peipman for the extension method on [his blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/12/28/stream-copyto-extension-method.aspx).

Comment: @DavidShochet Perhaps, perhaps not. They both accomplish the same thing, this will use less memory for very large file attachments since its buffered.